# How to create a path in powershell, which includes both directory and file?

Tags: powershell

I want to create a path in powershell which includes directory and file, I can create directory and files individually, but how can I create combinedly?

Comment: Could you edit the question and explain with more details? What do you mean by "path -- which includes directory and file"? An example would be nice.

Comment: ok... example path:    "D:\power\shell\ex.txt"

Answer (score 4):

```
New-Item -Path 'c:\a\b\c.txt' -Force
```

Will make folders `a`, `b` and file `c.txt`.

See: [This documentation on the `New-Item` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/New-Item?view=powershell-5.1), which says:

> **Example 3: Create a profile**
>
> [..] The *Force* parameter lets you create a file in the profile path, even when the directories in the path do not exist.

Comment: Might want to explain *why*

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I don't follow; why .. *what*? (That doesn't involve speculation about the reasons PowerShell cmdlets were designed one way instead of another way).

Comment: Why it will make the folders/file (explain `-Force` and/or point to its documentation)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 because someone designed it that way, I don't know why it will make them. OK, the documentation of New-Item's -Force parameter doesn't mention it, but one of the examples does, so I've added a link to that in the answer.

Comment: That's mostly due to the idea of providers and trying to be super generic in PowerShell so depending on the provider, force will do different things. For the filesystem provider, it will create the directory structure if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but I want files also in that path not only directories.

Comment: @jaas the last item is a file, not a directory